# Page edit only in HTML with TinyMCE

Tags: html, tinymce, editor, wysiwyg

I wanted to ask you, if anyone knows if you can edit an HTML page through a wysiwyg editor such as Tinymce..
Let me explain the project better: I would like to insert a button on each page of the site and once clicked take me to a page where there is a wysiwyg editor to go to edit it..

I would like to do something like this: INDEX.html >> page1.html >> i click on the button that brings me to the page pagedit.html (where the editor is presented) and from there I can edit the content.

Sorry if I have been long, but it’s been a few days that I’m trying but nothing, and for my English but I’m Italian!

Thanks